# Display queryset in template at the following order

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-filter

```
articles = Article.objects.all()
```

I need to display this articles queryset like:

1 ->  2 - > 3

6 < - 5 <-  4

7 ->  8 -> 9

Where `->`  - is css arrow class

```
{% for article in articles %}
    <div class="box">
        <span class="arrow-[left-right or bottom]"></span>
        <div class="title">{{ article.title }}</div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```